# image flickering like a strobe light

Tags: ios, image

I'm trying to create a magnet reset dot for my app, when someone clicks on the reset button it performs a reset of the hardware I use, and also flashes an orange circle from orange to green....

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


- (void)myMethod {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"orangeDot.png"];
    [dot setImage: image];

    sleep(1);

    image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"greenDot.png"];
    [dot setImage: image];

}
```

As you can see this occurs on a thread.

Anyway, here's my issue: The orangeDot is *not* being shown, even though there is a 1 second sleep?

Comment: You really shouldn't be updating the UI from outside the context of the main thread.  Maybe consider using a `NSTimer` or `CADisplayLink` instead. It would also be a better idea to preload your image resources instead of loading them inside `myMethod`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) onTick {

    [self battery];
}

- (void) resetMagnet:(UIButton *) sender {



    [[MySlateManager sharedManager] doReset];
    if(![SettingsManager shared].isVibrationDisabled)
    {
        [[VibrationHelper sharedInstance]singleShortVibration];
    }

    NSLog(@"Testttt");

    [self flickerOrange];


    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                  target: self
                                                selector:@selector(onTick)
                                                userInfo: nil repeats:NO];



}
```

That worked!